# setLayaut no respond to propriety Hgap

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, grid-layout

I tried to create an Interface graphic for the minesweeper game in java, but when I paint the gridLayaut with the JButton, I want the buttons were stuck, but I can't get it, and the buttons were separated.
This is my code:

```
    panelTablero.setLayout(new GridLayout(filas, columns,0,0));
    ReceptorBotones recepCelda = new ReceptorBotones();
    for (int x = 0; x < this.filas; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < this.columns; y++) {
            BotonCelda b = new BotonCelda(x, y);
            b.addMouseListener(recepCelda);
            panelTablero.add(b);
        }
    }
    panelTablero.revalidate();
    panelTablero.repaint();
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.add(panelTablero, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

And the result is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czbSV.png)

This is the complete method :
    private void pintarPanelTablero(NivelJuego pNivel) {

```
    this.filas = pNivel.get_alto();
    this.columns = pNivel.get_ancho();
    this.minas = pNivel.get_numMinas();
    this.minasRestantes = this.minas;

    // panel de tablero
    switch (nivelJuegoEnCurso) {
```

// the window's size depends of the game's level
        case 1:
            setBounds(20, 20, 535, 535);

```
        break;
    case 2:
        setBounds(20, 20, 800, 800);
        break;
    case 3:
        setBounds(20, 20, 1100, 1100);
        break;
    }

    panelTablero.removeAll();

    panelTablero.setLayout(new GridLayout(filas, columns));
    ReceptorBotones recepCelda = new ReceptorBotones();
    for (int x = 0; x < this.filas; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < this.columns; y++) {
            BotonCelda b = new BotonCelda(x, y);
            b.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
            b.addMouseListener(recepCelda);
            panelTablero.add(b);

        }
    }
    panelTablero.revalidate();
    panelTablero.repaint();
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.add(panelArriba, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    cp.add(panelTablero, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: `BotonCelda` probably has padding or margins/insets which is offsetting the content

Comment: @MadProgrammer is right. BotonCelda.setMargins(new Insets(0,0,0,0)) is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: The result is the same. It doesn't work

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this is the best advice we're going to be able provide you - everything else is simply guess work - which is just going to waste each others time

Comment: This is the complete method which I use:

Comment: *"This is the complete method which I use"* Did you read the document on the MCVE linked above? You should. It might help you to solve the problem, and if not, it will encourage others to run the code, looking for it. Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem with a negative value in the propriety Hgap. It's possible that the OS is the problem. I'm using iOS.

```
panelTablero.setLayout(new GridLayout(filas, columns, -5, -5));
```

[image]

Comment: BTW - by 'propriety' (good behavior or morals) DYM 'property' (an aspect of something) or 'proprietary' (relating to ownership)? That first word is almost certainly not what you mean.

Comment: No, I would say that the native look and feel is padding the button - this is probably coming from the `borderPainted` property. I'd be careful with using negative values in this may cause you "other" unexpected issues - just saying